# Sendkeys Numberpad Decimal

Tags: .net, decimal, ascii, sendkeys

I'm using sendkeys to try an invoke a prompt from a custom application. The numberpad decimal key is used to activate this prompt.

I cannot find the a way to do this in sendkeys, is it possible?

So far I've tired:

```
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(Chr(46))
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(Chr(46))
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send({DECIMAL})
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait({DECIMAL})
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.Send(".")
System.Windows.Forms.SendKeys.SendWait(".")
```

Any help would be great.

Comment: That application makes a distinction between period (the one usually a 2 keys right of the right shift on US keyboards) and the decimal of numeric keypad?

Comment: You need to use Windows APIs as far as I know.  See http://www.devx.com/vb2themax/Tip/19094

Comment: Try this -> [Windows Input Simulator (C# SendInput Wrapper - Simulate Keyboard and Mouse)](https://inputsimulator.codeplex.com/)

Comment: I don't quite understand, are you asking if it makes a distinctions or stating it does. You're correct on the key placement, I want to invoke the numberpad decimal and not the period, which is near the shift key.